I have an empty 32 GB usb stick and Ubuntu download at 5.8 GB says the file is too big
I have an empty 32 GB usb stick but Ubuntu 24.04 download at 5.8 GB says the file is too big

where is the proof of your claim?

Are you trying to copy ISO to FAT32 formatted partition? It must be installed or extracted. FAT32 only supports files up to 4GB.

Do not try to copy the downloaded ISO file into the USB drive. Follow the instructions on the Ubuntu website and "create a bootable USB drive" from the file.

if you really do just want to copy the .iso file to a USB stick then consider creating a Ventoy drive using these instructions
